# Cannot get build parameters in Jenkins Pipeline Job

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm trying to get some build parameters in a Jenkins pipeline job. In this context the parameters are defined in the checkbox "this project is parameterized" and passed at build time.

In the job I call two branches:

```
parallel firstBranch: {
    build job: 'Run Blah', parameters: [string(name: 'BLAH', value: '$app.blah.blah')]

}, secondBranch: {
    build job: 'Run BlahBlah', parameters: [string(name: 'BLAH', value: '$app.blah.blah')]
}
```

I've tried accessing the build parameter: app.blah.blah in these various ways:

- ${app.blah.blah}
- $app.blah.blah
- "${app.blah.blah}"
- app.blah.blah
- currentBuild.buildVariableResolver.resolve("app.blah.blah")
- System.getenv("app.blah.blah")

I always get some exception that I can somewhat understand, but I'm starting to get very annoyed. It should not be *this hard* to get a build parameter in the script for God's sake. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And in the job definition, you added a "String Parameter" with a name of "app.blah.blah" along with perhaps a default value?  Assuming that's all true, how did you pass the parameter to the build?

Comment: That's exactly it. I passed the parameter by running an on demand parameterized build. Ended up finding the solution tho; it was the dots in the parameter names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, looks like you can't have dots in your build parameter names! Confuses Groovy into thinking you're accessing a class. Sucks that I won't be able to keep my parameters consistent across Ant scripts and Jenkins jobs, but it's not a huge deal right now. If anyone knows how to access dotted variables, please feel free to add input!

Correct syntax for build parameter variable: `alphanumeric_underline_only`

Correct syntax for accessing: `println(alphanumeric_underline_only)`

Comment: For future readers, I suggest you edit your answer into a formal one that is clear and usable by other readers. Answers in this site a always very useful and come up in many google searches by developers. Explain how you fixed it along with an example of the right syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
println blah
```

So I guess it should be enough for you to do it like this:

```
parallel firstBranch: {
    build job: 'Run Blah', parameters: [string(name: 'BLAH', value: blah)]

}, secondBranch: {
    build job: 'Run BlahBlah', parameters: [string(name: 'BLAH', value: blah)]
}
```

Comment: Yeah it ended up being the dots in the build parameter name confusing Groovy. Spaces and dots beware!

Comment: You could try this too: ${app.blah.blah} but I still think groovy would consider each dot a function call.

Answer (score 0):

If your pipeline has parameter with the `dot` inside it name, you can try to get value of this parameter by using `getProperty()`, for example (tested):

```
//println params.MyApp.Api.Server // will not work
//println "${MyApp.Api.Server}" // will not work
println getProperty('MyApp.Api.Server') //works perfectly
```